# How can I replace the last comma in the string to "and" in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Just wandering, how can I replace the last comma in the string to "and" in SQL Server.

I have the following valuable:

```
@test = 'a,b,c,f,w'
```

How can I replace the last comma in the string to "and" as the output:

```
'a,b,c,f and w'
```

Comment: There are a lot of ways you could do it (e.g. one way would be to reverse the string, replace the first comma with ' dna ', then reverse the string again), but what have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is weird.  You can do:

```
set @test = left(@test, len(@test) - charindex(',', reverse(@test))) + ' and ' + stuff(@test, 1, len(@test) - charindex(',', reverse(@test)) + 1, '')
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to achieve it :

```
SELECT reverse(STUFF(reverse(@test), CHARINDEX(',', reverse(@test)), 1, ' dna '))
```

Comment: This assumes after last comma there will always be single character

Comment: Yes, you were correct, thanks, i have modified the query.